# Fluentd: How to place the time key inside the json string

Tags: fluentd

This is the record that fluentd write to my log.

```
2016-02-22 14:38:59 {"login_id":123,"login_email":"abc@gmail.com"}
```

The date time is the time key of fluentd. How can i place that time inside the json string ?

Answer (score 0):

My friend helped me this. He used this fluentd plugin:

```
http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/filter-plugin-overview
```

This is the config:

```
<filter trackLog>
   type record_modifier

        <record>
         fluentd_time ${Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
        </record>
 </filter>


<match trackLog>
  type record_modifier
  tag trackLog.finished

</match>

<match trackLog.finished>
 type webhdfs
 host localhost
 port 50070
 path /data/trackLog/%Y%m%d_%H
 username hdfs
 output_include_tag false
 remove_prefix trackLog.finished

 output_include_time false
 buffer_type file
 buffer_path /mnt/ramdisk/trackLog
 buffer_chunk_limit 4m
 buffer_queue_limit 50
 flush_interval 5s
</match>
```

Comment: Second record_modifier is not needed.

Comment: It  seems 'strftime' is not supported by record_modifier. I got error:

error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `strftime' for 1692326444:Integer" location="/opt/td-agent/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/time.rb:126:in `method_missing'" 

The 'strftime' is supported by slow 'record_tranformer' plugin, which has 'enable_ruby' parameter for that.

So, record_modifier is faster (w/o ruby), but I have no idea how to format time using it. 
It can only cast time object to string, according documentation:  formatted_time ${Time.at(time).to_s}